# $L^\infty(X)$, $X$ is a compact metric space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and let $m$ be a Borel probability measure on $X$ and consider $L^\infty(m)$. I want to prove that given a function $h \in L^\infty(m)$, there is a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ in $C(X)$ such that $|f_n(x)|\leq||h||_\infty$ for $m$ almost everywhere and $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=h(x)$ for $m$ almost all $x$. I dnt know how to prove it. I know $C(X)$ is not dense in $L^\infty(m)$. Am I missing any elementary result?

Answer (score 1):

If $h \in L^{\infty}(m)$ then $h \in L^{1}(m)$. Hence there exists sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous functions such that $|f_n| \leq \|h\|_{\infty}$ and $\int |f_n-h|dm \to 0$. But then there exists  a sub-sequence $(f_{n_k})$ of $(f_n)$ converging a.e. to $h$.

Comment: So you reduce to the same question for $L^1$, which you do not prove.  Why would the L^1$ result be known?